How to pass data to child of child in Vue3
I have a few components:
Show - Parent
Banner - Child of Parent
DropdownHover - Child of Banner
I'm passing the object (inspection) to banner: <Banner :inspection="inspection" />
Then, I'm passing the data again to DropdownHover: <DropdownHover :inspection="props.inspection" />
Then, finally, I'm attempting to pass the props.inspection.id to a link:
<template>
<li>
    <a :href="route('forms.generate', props.inspection.id)" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Generate Forms</a>
</li>
</template>

<script>
const props = defineProps({
    inspection: Object,
});
</script>

But, I'm getting an undefined type error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

If I try to console.log(props.inspection.id) it will print out the id once and then print out undefined.
Does anyone know why this might be happening? I think if I can get rid of that 2nd undefined everything will work perfect.

I added a v-if to the <li> element, and it solved my problem:
<li v-if="props.inspection && props.inspection.id">
    <a :href="route('forms.generate', props.inspection.id)" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Generate Forms</a>
</li>

